# How can I change the color of an anchor element when hovering over a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

Changing a color of a  element by hovering the mouse over

I have the following HTML

```
<p class="ItemMenu "><a href="">Inicio</a></p>                  
<p class="ItemMenu "><a href="#">Cadastro</a></p>
```

and CSS

```
.ItemMenu:hover
{
    color:white !important;
    background:#74BAF0;

}
```

how do I get my mouse inside the `<p>` my `<a>` text is white?

Comment: `.ItemMenu a:hover`?

Comment: `.ItemMenu:hover, .ItemMenu:hover a` if you want the `p` and the `a` color to change

Comment: Yea, it's unclear which color needs to change, I would think it's `p` and the `a` by the way it is currently coded

Answer (score 0):

To affect another element inside an element, you can try

```
.ItemMenu:hover a { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ItemMenu:hover a
{
    color:white !important;
    background:#74BAF0;

}
```

This should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<p class="ItemMenu"><a href="#">On hover over paragraph</a></p>
<p class="ItemMenu2"><a href="#">On hover over link</a></p>
```

CSS:

```
p.ItemMenu:hover
{
    color: black;
    background: #74BAF0;
}

p.ItemMenu:hover a
{
    color: black;
}

p.ItemMenu2 a:hover
{
    color: black;
    background: #74BAF0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oprPYR

But if you want to change the background of `p` after hover `a`... No, you can't do it - try to do it with using JS